# React | How to assign the same value to multiple element's attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, dictionary, attributes, use-state

### React Element's Attributes

Hey, I've been wondering to myselft if there's any way to assign the same value to few element's arributes.

see example below:

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {firstName: "", lastName: "", email: ""})

const formElement = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(formData))
{
    formElement.push(
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder={key} name={key} key={key}/>) // see here
}
```

As you may have noticed, I'm assiging the key value several times to input element's attributes.

There's shorter or easier way to handle this situation?

Thanks.